# How can I close the font panel programmatically?

Tags: cocoa

I am opening the sharedFontManager FontPanel from a preferences pane, and I want to close it when the preferences window is closed (or when I switch tabs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font panel is a subclass of NSPanel, which is a subclass of NSWindow.

```
[myFontPanel orderOut:self];
```

Comment: I was doing it with performClose. orderOut works too. I'm not sure what the difference is in this case.

Comment: I believe that performClose requires the window/panel to have a delegate that implements windowShouldClose whereas orderOut does now.